# Using ShellExecuteEx and capturing standard in/out/err

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm using `ShellExecuteEx` to execute a command in C. Is there a way to use `ShellExecuteEx` and capture standard in/out/err?

Note: I don't want to use `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by pilif and Bob, you need to use `CreateProcess`.

If you want code that wraps it all up for you, I do have a class for this exact issue at:

http://code.google.com/p/kgui/source/browse/trunk/kguithread.cpp.

The class (`kGUICallThread`) handles Linux, macOS and Windows versions. The code is licensed LGPL.

Comment: I believe the code moved to here: https://github.com/CarlHuff/kgui/blob/master/kguithread.cpp

Answer (score 9):

I use to found the problem like you.

Suppose, You want to capture the output from STDOUT that it's generated by **dir** command and save the captured into **out.txt**.

1. Use text editor and type **dir > out.txt** and save it with **mybat.bat** (*.bat, don't *.txt)
2. In your c/c++ program, type **WinExec("mybat.bat", SW_HIDE);** and run your application.
3. Open the **out.txt** you will see the name of folders and files in current directory.

Also, you can run any executable files (*.exe) at the same way as follow.

**xxx.exe > out.txt**

I hope it can be helps you.
Sorry, my English really not good.

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible. `ShellExecute`(`Ex`) basically executes the application in the context of the shell - so you are basically doing what explorer does.

Capturing STDIN and STDOUT is something the shell generally doesn't do, you you will have to go the `CreateProcess` route (which, after all, is what `ShellExecute` eventually calls if the file to execute is a program and the verb is 'open').

Answer (score 6):

No. The only way to do this is to use `CreatePipe` and `CreateProcess`. See the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

CreateProcess is what most people use.

You may also want to consider using _popen

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28VS.80%29.aspx