# Execute basic windows commands

Tags: ruby

I would like to achieve this using `win32ole` only and not any other way to execute shell commands in ruby.

```
require 'win32ole'
shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
my_username = shell.ShellExecute('cmd.exe', 'username', '', 'open', 0)
puts my_username

#Current output => nil
```

Just want to print my username but generally would like to execute any commands and get its output. I know we have `ENV['user']` or `echo %username%` gives me what I want but want this using win32ole only.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The second parameter to `ShellExecute` is `Directory`  and `username` in your case is nothing that's why you get `nil` output

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri: Tried out different ways, but still not able to get it to work. Can you please help

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri: directory is the third parameter, no? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for noticing you are correct

Comment: Does `cmd.exe` even accept commands as parameters this way?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I am not sure. All i want to do is basically execute commands from windows using ruby without a command prompt or a hidden one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You should try with `whoami` instead of `username`:</strike>

```
require 'win32ole'
shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')
my_username = shell.ShellExecute('cmd.exe', 'whoami', '', 'open', 0)
puts my_username
```

---

You *can't* use `ShellExecute()` because it doesn't let you access the output of the command your run which is what you want. See [Using ShellExecuteEx and capturing standard in/out/err](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469152/2307070) for more informations about that point.

I would simply use `puts ENV['USERNAME']` which works like a charm. (Or any command given by **Ilia Aptsiauri** in his answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute Windows CLI commands you need to take little bit different approach.
Instead of `whoami` you can put any command you want

- `system("whoami")`
- `whoami` (these are backticks)
- `spawn("whoami")`

The difference between those are the following

- system waits until "The command" has finished and outputs everything
  to $stdout. Then it returns true or false depending on the exitstatus.
- The backticks wait as well, but return the output made by the program.
- spawn doesn't wait, but rather returns the PID of the subprocess. Note
  that this requires Ruby 1.9 on Windows to work.

There is one more option check `Open3` library it get's little bit more information during the output.