# Redirecting process stdout for ShellExecute (or some other way to elevate and redirect)

Tags: windows, winapi, shellexecute

I am using bare Win32Api.
I need to launch app with elevated permissions and app has no manifest. So, the only way is to use `ShellExecuteEx` with `runAs` verb. It works, but I need to read process stdout. With `CreateProcess` I have `STARTUPINFO` which I can use to pipe process stdout.

But `ShellExecuteEx` does not have such API.
So, how can I elevate *and* redirect stdout?

Comment: Call ShellExecute to elevate and CreateProcess for redirection.

Comment: I also tried to add requireAdministrator to my manifest, but I need signature to prevent yellow warning

Comment: Well, get a code signing certificate then. Not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. To read stdout CreateProcess is required. But CreateProcess can't start another process elevated...

If possible create your own process that you may launch elevated. This process may capture stdout. Use some IPC to communicate with this process to get the stdout.

Or using simple pipe redirection.

This question has already been asked and is a [duplicate to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469152/using-shellexecuteex-and-capturing-standard-in-out-err).
See also this [question about elevating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893262/how-can-i-run-a-child-process-that-requires-elevation-and-wait).

Comment: "*CreateProcess can't start another process elevated*" - true, but [`CreateProcessElevated()`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) can.