# python console closes when opened from c++ with ShellExecuteEx

Tags: python, c++, winapi

I have to open a python script from c++. For this I decided to use ShellExecuteEx like below:

```
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = { 0 };
  ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
  ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
  ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
  ShExecInfo.lpFile = "python";
  ShExecInfo.lpParameters = strParams.c_str();
  ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
  ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
  ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
  ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
  WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
  CloseHandle(ShExecInfo.hProcess);
  size_t exeResult = (size_t)ShExecInfo.hInstApp;
  // check if the executable ran
  if (exeResult <= 32)
  {
```

However the python script ends without getting a chance to see the output error / traceback:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = open("python_log.txt", "w")
    f.write("hello")
    
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception occurred", str(e))
        f.write(str(e))
        var = traceback.format_exc()
        print(var)
        f.write(var)
        
    f.close()
    wait = input("Press Enter to exit.")
```

I don't know what else to add or how to see the output of the python script that is called by the c++ code. I've thought about running the cmd and start the py script from there, so that I have the output, but I didn't find a way to implement it in c++, it just starts the cmd and no calling the script.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ShellExecuteEx and capturing standard in/out/err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469152/using-shellexecuteex-and-capturing-standard-in-out-err)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `SEE_MASK_NO_CONSOLE` flag in the `fMask` member of the [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa) structure before calling [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa), then the Python interpreter will inherit your C++ program's console (assuming it is attached to one), instead of a new console being created for the Python interpreter. That way, your C++ program will have full control on when the console is closed. The console won't automatically be closed when the Python interpreter exits, as long as your C++ program is still running and attached to the console.

If your C++ program is not already attached to a console, then you can attach it to one by calling the function [`AllocConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole). You should do this before calling `ShellExecuteEx`.